# Wordpress REST Api request works on direct call but not from script

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

i have a problem using the WP REST API V2. I have two blogs on different urls and i want to load blog posts from one blog and show them in the second one. I thought using the WP REST API would be a good idea for this.

For the first blog if i open a url like this:

http://blog.example-a.de/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

i get all posts in json format.

On the second blog (let's call it blog.example-b.de) i created a page template file to load the blog posts from the first blog via the url above. After searching for examples for a while and reading documentation, the shortest solution seemed to be something like this:

```
$request = WP_REST_Request::from_url('http://blog.example-a.de/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'); 
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
$response = $wp_rest_server->response_to_data($body, true);
```

But when i do this i get an error:

> array(3) { ["code"]=> string(13) "rest_no_route" ["message"]=> string(85) "No route was found matching the URL and request method" ["data"]=> array(1) { ["status"]=> int(404) } }

And now i am a little bit stuck on this. I can not figure out why it works when i directly call the url in a browser but not from the script...

I tried another method to fetch data from the API:

```
$request = wp_remote_get( 'http://blog.example-a.de/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' );
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
$data = json_decode( $body );
```

And surprisingly this works. *Edit: This does give me some data, but not the data i need in the format i need.*

I am pretty sure there must be something i am missing, maybe someone around here has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as second way works, go for that. Don't waste much time overthinking that.

Comment: The second way only works so far that i can get some data from the API but not the data i need. If i could use the appropriate functions i would get correctly formatted post objects.